# Select part of an email chain in table

Tags: sql, email, ssrs-2008, chain

I am trying to run an SSRS report which selects all the emails which have formed part of a CRM case. However, where those emails maybe part of a chain I want to select down to the end of the first email. So far I have the following code, however it has not worked and the report has selected all of the emails in the chain:

The marker for the start of a new email is the word 'From:'

How can I not select anything from after that word?

```
SELECT
     FilteredActivityPointer.createdbyname
    ,FilteredActivityPointer.createdon

    ,CASE 
         WHEN FilteredActivityPointer.description LIKE '%from: %' THEN 
             SUBSTRING (FilteredActivityPointer.description, 1, CHARINDEX('From: ', FilteredActivityPointer.description)-1)
         ELSE 
             FilteredActivityPointer.description 
         END AS ActivityDescription
  ,FilteredActivityPointer.activitytypecodename
  FROM
  FilteredActivityPointer
INNER JOIN FilteredIncident ON FilteredActivityPointer.regardingobjectid = FilteredIncident.incidentid 
WHERE
       FilteredIncident.ticketnumber = 'CASE1'
```

Comment: Is your db Case Sensitive? You're searching for `from` in the LIKE but `From' in the CHARINDEX.

Comment: It is not case sensitive. For this to work I had to include the HTML code for the space. Therefore %from:</span> %